# Google Calendar API between two organizations

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am working with the Google Calendar API and developing a web app for a construction company to be able to sync all of their work within a single Google Calendar through the application.

They are able to set up all of the tasks that need to get done within the app and then it will be organized and added to the Google Calendar.

All of this works.....expect I can't get people from other organizations have access to the calendar. Right now I have it set up that the calendar the app is using, is the calendar that I set up within my Google Apps Business account. I have tested it with other Google Accounts and consistently get a forbidden message. It only works with my business account since it's the one that created it.

I have my business google app account settings set to allow people from outside the organization and I have added the other google users to the calendars sharing settings with "Make changes and manage sharing".

Is there something I'm missing? This seems like it should be straight forward but I must have a setting missing somewhere.

Comment: I'm thinking this is not related to the api, any of the code, or stackoverflow. Seems like this is a question about how to use google apps for business- as this should be as simple as sharing it with the other users. https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en Also, there is more discussion on sharing to an entire organization here: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/4c1T67Qo-N0/SntmeTlUInIJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendars created in the Google for Work setup are subject to the domain restrictions see the "For google Apps" section here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing

You will need to either get the setting changed in the admin console or create a different calendar (through a gmail.com account).